# How can I make smooth lines starting at the same point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I first used `geom_line`, and it returns the output that I want. But when using `geom_smooth` with curvilinear formula, each line then started from different points which make comparison between line harder. How can I fix this, so all fitted lines start from the bottom of the Y-axis?

Code:

```
ggplot(data = induction, 
       mapping = aes(x = time_min, y = A_state, color = treatment_p, shape = treatment_p))+ 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))+ 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x = "a" , y = "b%")+ 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 2), 
        legend.position = "none" )+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 1.5)+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 50, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 1.5)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,25,50,75,90,100))
```

plot using smooth:
[image: plot using smooth]

plot using line:
[image: plot using line]

Comment: 'ggplot(data = induction, 
       mapping = aes(x = time_min, y = A_state, color = treatment_p, shape = treatment_p))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))+
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "a" , y = "b%")+
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 2),
    legend.position = "none"
  )+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 90, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 1.5)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 50, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 1.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,25,50,75,90,100))'

Comment: Where is 'induction' from? Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question without the data, but you may want to try a higher order polynomial in the formula argument of geom_smooth().  Maybe y ~ poly(x, 4).